# Java Ehcache Upgradation from 2.5 to 2.6

Tags: java, ehcache, ehcache-bigmemory

I want to upgrade my ehcache from 2.5 to 2.6 version. What i want to know is , is it possible to read already built 2.5 version ehcaches (*.data and *.index files) in 2.6 version ?

Comment: I believe you should submit this question to the support.

Comment: can you please paste the support team link here?

Comment: According to the website and releases notes here : https://confluence.terracotta.org/display/release/Ehcache+2.6.0+Release+Notes You may mail someone with the adress at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume this question relates to the OpenSource disk store, configured in a persistent mode.

The short answer is: no, this is not supported.